# Distance Matrix PostGis

Tags: python, postgis, distance, distance-matrix

Assuming I have a table or 2 dimensional array with only geometries and names (all in all 5k elements)

```
name     the_geom
a        polygon_geometry....
b        polygon_geometry....
c        polygon_geometry....
d        polygon_geometry....
e        polygon_geometry....
f        polygon_geometry....
...      ...
```

Is there a way to get the distances of all geometries to all geometries within one table.

```
    a    b    c    d    e    f    .... 
a   -    2m   3m   2m   2m   2m
b   2m   -    3m   5m   1m   9m
c   9m   3m   -    2m   7m   2m
d   ..   ..   ..   -    ..   ..
e   ..   ..   ..  ..    -    ..
f   ..   ..   ..  ..    ..   -
....
```

All hints are welcomed. Python hints as well!

Comment: What do the 2m, etc represent. Pairwise distances between each geometry?

Comment: @JohnBarça yes. the distance from `a to b` (row 1) is `2 metres`. The distance between `a and c` (row 1) is `3 metres` and so on...

Comment: While it is trivial to calculate all pair wise distances, doing crosstabs in Postgres is really painful ,see [tablefunc docs for how](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html). You would probably be better off using pandas, possibly in conjunction with geopandas for the distances. See the [pandas crosstab funcs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html).

Comment: @JohnBarça Yep. I thought it might be better to use python (numpy/scipy) to do this...

Comment: Pandas, rather than numpy/scipy, but, yes. Sadly, I have the world's worst internet connection, and don't have time to write this up.

Comment: Do you want them all in a table like that, or can you handle `place1|place2|distance` eliminating the need to use `crosstab`.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yes, a matrix like this is needed.

Comment: is `name` unique?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yes

Comment: the trick is that the matrix is symmetric so you only (!) need n^2/2 calculations

Comment: Can we generate this grid with psql? Rather than through the SQL api? Output the results of `psql -v`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, I don't think this pivot can be done in PostgreSQL however the distance calculation certainly can be. First you need a simple table of the distances, because `ST_Distance` and all distance calculations are [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) you can do something like this,

```
SELECT
  t1.geom_name AS t1,
  t2.geom_name AS t2,
  ST_Distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)
FROM table AS t1
INNER JOIN table AS t2 on (t1.geom<t2.geom);
```

You may want to get the entire list with duplicate tuples too (if it makes it easier to assemble this grid in your desired language).

```
SELECT
  t1.geom_name AS t1,
  t2.geom_name AS t2,
  ST_Distance(t1.geom, t2.geom)
FROM table AS t1
CROSS JOIN table AS t2;
```

From there in python you have to recreate the grid. Or, something else like `\crosstabview` in [psql 9.6](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159339/2639).