# PostGIS Distance between vertex

Tags: postgis

I want to filter lines which represent ship movement in a manner, that linestrings where the distance between two vertexes is greater than 1000 km are removed.
I have a piece of code, however I am getting the error message that the function ST_Distance does not exist.

```
> ERROR:  function st_distance(geometry_dump, geometry_dump) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_Distance(ST_DumpPoints(a.line), ST_DumpPoints(b.li...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_DumpPoints(a.line), ST_DumpPoints(b.line)) dist
FROM ais_2017_09_move a, ais_2017_09_move b 
WHERE mmsi = 566035000
AND dist < 1000;
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not that ST_Distance doesn't exist, its that PostGIS can't find the correct ST_Distance function for the arguments you gave it. Check the error message:

```
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.
```

So what arguments are you giving it? Two outputs from `ST_DumpPoints`.

The documentation https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html says that it returns `geometry_dump` rows, and it seems `ST_Distance` doesn't know how to compute distances across those.

To do what I think you are trying to do it looks like you'll need to dump the points and then compute the distances grouped by the first element of the `path` part of the returned dump. See the doc for an example. I don't have handy access to a PostGIS server at the moment to try.

Also, as written, even you are calling `ST_Distance` on the same two things (with a different alias) and `ST_Distance` works row-by-row meaning you'll end up with a column of zeroes. To compute a distance matrix you have to join two geometry columns together. See [Distance Matrix PostGis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222622/distance-matrix-postgis) for example.